# How do tell if using QorIQ LS1021 hardware acceleration for encryption?

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am currently testing the capabilities of using the QorIQ LS1021's encryption capabilities using openSSL. Is there a way of determining if my code is taking advantage of the chips hardware accelerated encryption engine? Perhaps a register to look at or something.

Comment: OpenSSL may provide some custom ASM if it detects the LS1021 hardware. However, grepping the 1.0.2 sources shows 0 hits for `grep -iIR LS1021 *`. There are no relevant hits for NXP, either.